# Creating grafana dashboards using terraform/cdktf

Tags: grafana, panel, dashboard, terraform-cdk

I can create influxdb datasources and alerts using cdktf for grafana.

The only thing missing are the actual dashboards.
So far I have been using grafonnet, which appears to be deprecated.

Is it possible to create dashboards and panels using cdktf yet, if so, how?

Comment: What exactly is the problem. I'd think that if you already provisioned alert rules, dashboards shouldn't be a problem according to this [Grafana provisioning tutorial](https://grafana.com/tutorials/provision-dashboards-and-data-sources/).

Comment: The problem is the actual dashboard definition: As the link states, the creation of the jsons can be done using:

    - grafana-dash-gen (Javascript)
    - grafanalib (Python)
    - grafonnet-lib (Jsonnet)
    - grafyaml (YAML)

However, tying the uids, names and id together for data-sources, alerts, dashboards, panels and notifiers is rather inelegant.

Comment: I am currently creating data sources, and alerts via cdktf. The dashboards via grafanalib. The alert creation via cdktf is an unholy mess, though. Maybe I can extract the models from a grafanalib-alert rule.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`grafana_dashboard`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/grafana/grafana/latest/docs/resources/dashboard) resource from the grafana provider. For this you have to add the provider if you haven't already, e.g. by running `cdktf provider add grafana`.

Your code could look like this

```
import { Dashboard } from "./.gen/providers/grafana/lib/dashboard";
import { TerraformAsset } from "cdktf";
import * as path from "path";


// in your stack

new Dashboard(this, "metrics", {
  config: Fn.file(
    // Copies the file so that it can be used in the context of the
    // Stack deployment
    new TerraformAsset(this, "metrics-file", {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "config.json")
    }).path
  )
})
```